# How do I cut power inside a main panel when there's no service disconnect present?

Tags: circuit-breaker

I am trying to install a 50A circuit breaker for a 14-50 outlet. I'd like to put that breaker in the main panel of the house.

Looking at my panel I cannot figure out how to cut power to the whole panel. There doesn't seem to be a service disconnect anywhere. I can see breakers which feed: a subpanel in the garage, the oven, the AC, the irrigation system, and the telephone/TV panel. But no main breaker or service disconnect. What am I missing?

The only other things on this panel are 2 sections: 1 where the meter sits (below the pictured panel) and, next to it, a section that's sealed off by the electric company (PG&E). Could my service disconnect be in the street (there's a bolted down box in my front lawn), or in the sealed box?

Thank you!

[image: house main panel]

Comment: The thing in the middle of the bottom may be a fuse block with the fuses attached to the cover that you pull off to disconnect the box. The disconnect could also be in the sealed box. You may be expected to break the seal and disconnect the entire panel only in an emergency. You would then call the PG&E to check everything and close the main disconnect.

Comment: I have always added or changed breakers without opening the main disconnect, but I don't think I did that prior to getting my PE license.

Comment: Not all panels have a main disconnect in them.  Zinsco is made this way.  My brother blew apart a screwdriver just the other day working on one of those.   You can unplug the meter, but PGE will slap your wrist.  Choose your slapper, PGE or 240V-AC

Comment: Or you can call PGE and have them unplug the meter, and plug it back in when you are done.

Comment: @Aaron I can't speak for PG&E (Ca) but I can speak about a conversation with PGE (Or.) If you ask for a service disconnect, they'd do that "promptly." And they just don't mind. But if you then ask for a service connect, they'll require a signature from a licensed electrician about the panel they are connecting in order to reconnect the service. It's "easy off" and "not so easy back on." If you can find a licensed electrician who will lend their signature after doing a quick check on your work, fine. But my experience with them as a group is that most are at least "mildly upset" with the idea.

Comment: @user263983 At the bottom are two black-insulated bus bar "wires", probably leading down into the PG&E meter section.

Comment: @DoxyLover Oh, I see. But looks stranger. Disconnect has to be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's really nothing wrong with plugging a new breaker into a "hot" panel. But if you're not comfortable doing it, then you need to hire an electrician.

You are already aware that the exposed plates that run behind all of the breakers and the "blades" that the breakers grab onto carry line voltage, right?

As long as the breaker itself is in the "off" position, you can install it into the panel. Just keep your fingers away from that exposed plate.

In fact, if it were me, I'd put another double breaker into the other unused position (at least temporarily) in order to cover up the rest of that plate while I pull the new wire into the box and connect it to the breaker.

Comment: Thank you! I don't mind snapping in the breaker in a hot panel, while the breaker is off, of course. What I'd want to know is if it's safe to connect the ground and the neutral to the neutral bus. I was also confused to see that the neutral and ground wires are all connected to the same bus, they are separate in my subpanel, but upon reading more it seems that's the way it should be.

Comment: Yes, subpanels must keep ground and neutral separate. The only place they are connected (indeed, must be connected) is in the main panel.

Comment: @DaveTweed I'd like to disagree with the last sentence above. Consider Section 250.32 in NEC? And types listed in 250.52(A)(1)-(8), and 250.50. But I may also be talking at cross-purposes or am missing something.

Comment: Electricians are not allowed to work under voltage except special cases, which is not this one. If subpanel less then 3 meters from main, disconnect should be where.

Comment: I installed a standby hole house genset and the inspector checked to be sure the neutral and ground were bonded only in the main main disconnect. In my case that was the transfer switch. He also checked the grounding, I have a ground array so I was AOK with this. This is in Michigan USA. We are required to run 4 wires to 220v capable branch panels which yours appears to be. They are phase A, phase b, netural, and earth ground(Green) which is connected to the box. There cannot be any connection between the neutral and earth ground in the branch panel. Mike Holt also states this on his web site.

Comment: @Gil I read Mike Holt, too. But NEC ***§250.32: Buildings or Structures Supplied by a Feeder(s) or Branch Circuit(s).*** *(A) Grounding Electrode. Building(s) or structure(s) supplied by feeder(s) or branch circuit(s) shall have a grounding electrode or grounding electrode system installed in accordance with Part III of Article 250.* In general, as I gather it up, the grounding electrode must be of types listed in §250.52(A)(1) through (8). A Ufer isn't required by the NEC, but if one exists it ***must*** be connected using a grounding electrode per §250.50. Or am I reading all this wrong?

Comment: I'm not sure what this debate is about. My comment was strictly about where the "grounded" (neutral) and "grounding" conductors should and should not be connected together in the distribution wiring. The question of how the system is actually connected to earth is a completely separate issue.